# ExtJS: datagrid: re-apply sorting / refresh after loading

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I've been looking for it for such a long time, and (from my own point of view) this is a basic behavior that should've been done a long time ago: you sort a grid by a column, say "`NAME`", you modify a record, the name "`AAA`" becomes "`ZZZ`", it's sent to the server, the server answers "ok" with "`ZZZ`" so the value is updated but stays **at the same place**, i.e. the sort order is not refreshed.

Is there a way to do this automatically? Which event, which code? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked on the [Sencha's forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?200412-ExtJS-datagrid-re-apply-sorting-refresh-after-loading) and for the first time in history I've got the answer there before on stackoverflow. So, to share the answer, here's my code that works:

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.StoreHandleErrors', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'data.storehandleerrors',

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.callParent([config]);

        this.on(
            'write',
            function(me, opts) {
                this.sort();
            },
            this
        );
    }
});
```

Explanation: I'm overriding the constructor so that each time the "write" event is called i.e. each time the record is sent to the server, this re-sort the store so that we are always sure it's properly refreshed. This is a generic method that may be "too much" (= no need to re-sort again for *each* write) but (1) it works for *all* stores (2) no need to make custom hard-coded stuff like Abdel suggested (although Abdel's answer may be more suitable to make it only once in a specific piece of code).

Comment: Actually I can't understand your code.  It would great if you add some explanation to yours.

Answer (score 3):

You could call the store method explicitly once you get "ok" from server. something like:

```
myStore.sort("name","ASC");
```

Or if you have a collection of sorting columns you could make use of the `sorters` property available with the store. Like:

```
myStore.sort(myStore.sorters); // this uses the existing sorting rules applied to the store
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for me `myStore.sort("name","ASC");` your first solution works flawlessly.  whereas you second is not.  I think you 2nd has some bug in there.  Since I'm new to ext.js I was not able to figure it out.  I will try and it I find it, I will let you know.  Anyway thanks.

Comment: @Praveen For the second solution to work you need to define sorters on the store like this: `sorters: [{ property: 'name', direction: 'ASC' }]`